# Swift • How can I initiate a Background Task from a View's Initializer?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, multithreading, swiftui

I am working on a `SwiftUI App` and encountered a problem.

> I have a View *(`File Icon`)*. A `Data` object is passed to this View. To create the `File Icon`, the Data must be converted into a PDFDocument and an Image must be rendered from the first Document Page.

**Idea:** Since this is a heavy task and there are Views that display multiple File Icons *(e.g. 20 File Icons are created at the same time)*, the plan is to create the `File Icon` with some sort of placeholder, render the image in a Background Queue and, once its finished, change the displayed Image.

**Code:**

```swift
struct FileIcon: View {
    let data: Data
    @State private var image: UIImage?

    init(for data: Data) {
        self.data = data

        renderImage() // Initiate the Background Task
    }

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if let safeImage = image {
                // Some Placeholder View
            } else {
                Image(uiImage: safeImage)
            }
        }
    }

    private func renderImage() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            // Heavy Logic

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                image = renderedImage
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem:**
As you can see, I am initiating the `Background Task` inside the `View's Initializer`. Xcode does not give any Error. However, when running this Code, the Placeholder View keeps being displayed and there is no switch to the actual rendered Image.
when calling `renderImage()` inside `.onAppear()`, the placeholder get replaced by the rendered image after some time.

**Question:** How can I initiate a `Background Task` from a `View's Initializer`?

Comment: have you tested with breakPoints if call is even going inside “main.async” when called from init()?

Comment: You would rather not do that, because View init can be called many times. Do this instead in some view model or manager, which workflow you can control.

Comment: @Asperi thank you for your answer. However, can I initiate a `Background Task` in the `Initializer` of the `View Model`? It seems to me that I'll have the same problem then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple demo (as you want to do it in `init`, however, since I don't know your scenario, probably it is better to move it into separated method and call explicitly)

Tested with Xcode 12.5 / iOS 14.5

```
struct DemoBackgroundTaskView: View {

    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var finished = false

        init() {
            print("Init") // test called once

            // set up once performed background task
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

                sleep(10) // do your long task here

                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    self?.finished = true
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @StateObject private var vm = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Text(vm.finished ? "Done" : "Loading...")
    }
}
```